# is there a shadow ban feature on stack for moderators to utilize?

Tags: discussion, moderation

is it possible to hide comments from uses with out them finding out? like can any moderator shadow ban a user without their knowledge? just because that user is gaining points with decent answers?

or do users get to see why and who deleted the answer/comment

if not how can this feature be monitored and prevented from being abused.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no shadow ban feature on Stack Exchange.

Please see https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment for guidance about when leaving a comment is appropriate.

Once again, use the "Contact" link at the bottom of every page if you believe that moderators are acting inappropriately.